# How do I toggle the background colors within a list of divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

From a list of items, each in separate divs, the user can select and click only one. The background color should change on the selected one. If the user changes their mind, they can select another one, and the background color should change to the selected color and all the other divs on the list should change back to the default background color.

It's basically the same logic as a radio button on a form. Only one can be selected at a time.

How do I achieve this?

I have attempted to use the element.classList.toggle property. But it only handles each individually. Are there a javascript command(s) to handle this?

```
    <style> 
    .teamSelected{
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    </style>

    <div  onclick="toggleBackground(team1)"> 
            <div id="team1">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div  onclick="toggleBackground(team2)"> 
            <div id="team2">
            </div>
    </div> 
    <div  onclick="toggleBackground(team3)"> 
            <div id="team3">
            </div>
    </div>  


    <script>
       function toggleBackground(teamnumber) {
                var element = document.getElementById(teamnumber);
                    if (element) {
                        element.classList.toggle("teamSelected");  
                    }
                }
    </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you post full code of the problem?

Comment: onclick="toggleBackground(team1)" <-- team1 is a variable name (which is undefined), but you're passing to your function, which expecting a string.

Use: onclick="toggleBackground('team1')"

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your work in a snippet for us to review.

Comment: so select the others and remove the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing variables to the function, which don't exist. You need to put them in quotes, because the function is expecting strings.

```js
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

function toggleBackground(teamnumber) {
  var element = document.getElementById(teamnumber);
  if (element) {
    allDivs.forEach(function(el){
      el.classList.remove('teamSelected');
    });
    element.classList.add("teamSelected");
  }
}
```

```css
.toggle > div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
.teamSelected {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="toggleBackground('team1')" class="toggle">
  <div id="team1" class="div">
  </div>
</div>
<div onclick="toggleBackground('team2')" class="toggle">
  <div id="team2" class="div">
  </div>
</div>
<div onclick="toggleBackground('team3')" class="toggle">
  <div id="team3" class="div">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! I'll try this and const. Thanks!@

Comment: Thanks @YaakovAinspan!! It worked!

What if you want this to only affect certain divs but not all divs in the document?

I assigned a class to only the divs I want to apply this:

        div > div.onlythis {
            background-color: #fff;
         }

and css:

        div > div.onlythis {
            background-color: #fff;
         }

But it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. This only affects certain targeted elements.

Comment: Hi, The document has other divs where I dont want the toggle background to happen. In the css: 
    div > div {
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       border: 1px solid #000;
 }
it affects all divs, including divs for the menu, the footer, etc.
I only want the togglebackground to affect the divs where the on-click is in. How can I code it so it only affects the divs I want. I assume assigning them with a class is part of the solution.
Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, see updated snippet. Just add a class (in my snippet, `.toggle`) and target that class instead of all `div`s.

Comment: Thanks Yaakov! I appreciate it. i have a lot to learn. Taking a JS class now.

Answer (score 0):

seems like this is something you want?

```js
let x = ('.something');
$(x).on('click', function(){
$(x).css('background','blue');
$(this).css('background', 'green');
});
```

```css
.something{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div  class="something"> 
            <div id="team1">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="something"> 
            <div id="team2">
            </div>
    </div> 
    <div  class="something"> 
            <div id="team3">
            </div>
    </div>
```